# worker pool vs libuv's threadpool in node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, libuv

I was reading node.js docs about [worker pool](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#what-code-runs-on-the-worker-pool) and faced two term which I thought both are same - `worker pool` and `libuv's threadpool`.

Here is the point of confusion (from node.js doc url):

These are the Node module APIs that make use of this Worker Pool:

**I/O-intensive**

**DNS:** `dns.lookup()`, `dns.lookupService()`.

File System: All file system APIs **except `fs.FSWatcher()` and those that are explicitly synchronous use libuv's threadpool**.

Here is my understanding so far:

`event loop` -> can be considered main thread

`worker pool` -> which is implemented by libuv, so in that case worker pool thread is actually libuv thread.

So, how workers pool does something without libuv's thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Worker Pool" and "libuv's threadpool" are the same. The reason you're misunderstanding is due to the formulation of that sentence. As a non-native English speaker myself, I can see why.

This:

> File System: All file system APIs except `fs.FSWatcher()` and those that are explicitly synchronous use libuv's threadpool.

could instead be formulated like this:

> File System: All file system APIs use libuv's threadpool, except `fs.FSWatcher()` and those that are explicitly synchronous.

A better formulation can be seen on the docs for [`UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_uv_threadpool_size_size) cli option, as seen here:

> Node.js APIs that use the threadpool are:
>
> - ...
> - all zlib APIs, other than those that are explicitly synchronous